# what are the local database in flutter suitable for POS system?

Tags: flutter

Please help me to find what are the local databases used in flutter and from that which is suitable for  developing POS system

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow ! Stackoverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question, and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot depends on how you want your system to work, how many users are expected, is there a web version, where the server application is hosted and so on.

With reference to the local databases, you can either use Sqlite which will is one of the most popular or you can also use Firebase database. Both have their own plus-and-minus points. You'll have to weigh them to check what fits for your application.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you must try [firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore)

Comment: Firestore is not the database system. How did you figure Firestore is the most suited for a POS ?